# Does C always evalute all statements connected with && or ||

Tags: c, evaluation

pretty simple question I have here, but I couldn't find the answer:

Assume I have some conditional clause made up of several conditions. E.g. something like

```
  if((a == b && strcmp(string1, string)) || x <= 5)
```

My question is: Will all of those statements be evaluated, no matter what the result of the first ones was, or will the evaluation stop once the result is clear.

As I am not sure whether my question is clear, here's an example:

```
  if(a == 5 || b > 12 || (c = someFun()) == 3)
```

In this case, if a == 5, no further checks would be required, because the result of the big statement is TRUE, so we could simply continue. This would mean that someFun() would not be evaluated.

Is this the case? I know Java makes a difference here between && and & resp. || and | (the latter aren't available in C anyways), but I do not know how C handles this

Comment: `|` and `&` *are* available in C.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

These operators are [short-circuiting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) in C (and C++).

Comment: Short circuit evaluation... That was the term I was looking for, but just couldn't remember it anymore :)

Answer (score 5):

C evaluates until it knows the answer, so:

EvalsToTrue() && EvalsToAnything() evaluates both

EvalsToFalse() && EvalsToAnything() evaluates only the first

EvalsToTrue() || EvalsToAnything() evaluates only the first

EvalsToFalse() || EvalsToAnything() evaluates both

Answer (score 1):

The left-hand side expression is always evaluated.  The right-hand side expression is evaluated as follows:

- `a || b` -- `b` will be evaluated only if `a` evaluates to `false`
- `a && b` -- `b` will be evaluated only if `a` evaluates to `true`

`&&` has higher precedence than `||`, thus

- `a || b && c` -- `b && c` will be evaluated only if `a` evaluates to `false`
- `a && b || c` -- `c` will be evaluated only if `a && b` evaluates to `false`
- `(a || b) && c` -- `c` will  be evaluated only if `a || b` evaluates to `true`
- `a && (b || c)` -- `b || c` will be evaluated only if `a` evaluates to `true`
- `a && b && c` -- `c` will be evaluated only if `a && b` evaluate to `true`
- `a || b || c` -- `c` will be evaluated only if `a || b` evaluate to `false`

Answer (score 0):

Evaluation starts at left most.. and exits when the overall condition is no longer valid..